# RegEx to replace links avoiding html special characters

Tags: php, html, regex, hyperlink

I'm trying to replace url links (starting http:// ...) to html hyperlinks in a string with PHP, I use a regex for this, but the problem is there's conflicts with the html "&nbsp ;" characters.

So I used this, it seems to work with normal links, but if I add the rule `(^&[^;]+?;)` to avoid specials characters it doesn't work.

```
function shortlink($text) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/(^|[^"])(((f|ht){1}tps?:\/\/)(^&[^;]+?;)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:;\[\]%_\+.~#!?&\/\/=]+)/i',
        'url_link',
        $text
    );
}
```

And this is the callback function:

```
function url_link($match) {
    return $match[1].'<a href="'.$match[2].'" target="_blank">'.(strlen($match[2])>50 ? substr($match[2], 0, 24).'<i>'.substr($match[2], 24, 1).'</i><span class="shortl">'.substr($match[2], 25, -19).'</span>'.substr($match[2], -19) : $match[2]).'</a>';
}
```

But this:

```
function shortlink($text) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/(^|[^"])(((f|ht){1}tps?:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:;\[\]%_\+.~#!?&\/\/=]+)/i',
        'url_link',
        $text
    );
}
```

Work fine, but the conflict still exists.

This example illustrates the problem. If I have a string

```
http://any_link&quote;
```

this gives =>

```
<a href="http://any_link'">...
```

But I want :

```
<a href="http://any_link">
```

Any solution?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. The `^` in `(^&[^;]+?;)` means match begin of string. If you put it directly in the middle of your expression it would fail directly. Anyways, there's a lot of redundancy in your expression, for example `{1}` or escaping some characters in a character class etc... I think you want to take a look at `html_entity_decode()` or take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/406230). Btw, GTO is awesome.

Comment: Refer to your link, I have to add a capture at the end of regex `'/(^|[^"])(((f|ht){1}tps?:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:;\[\]%_\+.~#!?&\/\/=]+)(?:(?!&[^;]+?;).)/i',`  but it totally change my regex btw. A way to add a non-capturing rule?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

```
(f|ht){1}tps
```

This will only work with secured connections (`httpS`, `ftpS`). It won't match `http` or `ftp`.

Comment: You need to take a look one character further `(f|ht){1}tps?`. The question mark makes the `s` optional.